# Send HTML output when new values inserted in DB

Tags: php, html

I need to trigger a php file every 5 seconds to check for updates how its possible without using

1) HTML5 Server Events

2) Ajax & Settimeout / set interval In Javascript

As i have already tried using the above mentioned way's is there any alternative way to get instant updates from php.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the stateless nature of http and the request-response mechanism that makes it work, the only way to check for updates is by polling at regular intervals, which is indeed inefficient.
A possible way to mitigate that is by maintaining a server side timestamp to be updated through a database trigger each time the concerned table is updated. That way, the polling will be less expensive since only a check of this flag will be necessary instead of the full blown query that returns the actual data. Further optimization can be done such as having the table containing the timestamp in memory and using a stored procedure to both check the timestamp and issue the query for the updated data if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your script works in linux, you can use a crontab.
For Example:

```
* * * * * php update_checker.php
```

That means "update_checker.php" script will be excecute every minutes. 
This is my reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Crontab have a limitation: at least the script is processed every 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

With a cronjob, something like this:

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/script.php
```